# Symfony2 how to join on many-to-many relations using querybuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Being new to symfony2 and querybuilder, I am trying to select all my containers but limiting the result to only those for which the logged-in user has access.

With the current code I get this error:

Notice: Undefined index: Container in /var/www/biztv_symfony/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php line 746

Here is my attempt at the query (I have tried a couple of options from this and other forum sites and still can't seem to understand it right...)

```
public function indexAction()
{
    //Get the requisits        
    $companyId = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getCompany()->getId();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    //Fetch the containers
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BizTVContainerManagementBundle:Container');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->innerJoin('c.users','u')
        ->where('c.company = :company')
        ->setParameter('company', $companyId)
        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();
    $containers = $query->getResult();
```

I keep track of access with a many-to-many relation, this is my user entity...

```
<?php
// src/BizTV/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace BizTV\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company as company;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;  

    /**
    * @var object BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company
    *  
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    */
    protected $company; 

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BizTV\ContainerManagementBundle\Entity\Container", inversedBy="User")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="access")
     */
    private $access;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->access = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }
//getters and setters...
```

This is my container entity:

```
<?php

namespace BizTV\ContainerManagementBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use BizTV\UserBundle\Entity\User as user;

/**
 * BizTV\ContainerManagementBundle\Entity\Container
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="container")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Container
{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Du måste ange ett namn för området") 
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
    //TODO: form handler assuring no name is used twice in same company

    /**
    * @var object BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company
    *  
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    */
    protected $company; 

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BizTV\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="Container")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Container` entity, when you specify the `$users` property mapping, the value of `mappedBy` is important: you need to specify the **name** of the inverse property in the `User` class.

Here, we have, `Container::$users` <-> `User::$access`.

Change your annotations to:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BizTV\ContainerManagementBundle\Entity\Container", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="access")
     */
    private $access;
}

class Container
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BizTV\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="access")
     */
    private $users;
}
```

I encourage you to read the [doctrine orm documentation part about associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional), and verify and fix this in all your associations.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the docs thoroughly enough, I thought the inversedBy and MappedBy were table names, not field names...